# jQuery code is not working in second page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have following script to show the ratings for courses. But it is working properly for pagination first page showing 5 stars, when it comes to second page it showing 10 stars. Code is like below,

```
<div class="ft-item">
    <div class="rating_<?php echo $row->courseId;?>">
</div>
<script>
    $('.rating_<?php echo $row->courseId;?>').raty({
        starOff : '<?php echo base_url()?>public/images/star/icon-star-2.png',
        starOn  : '<?php echo base_url()?>public/images/star/icon-star-1.png',
        starHalf: '<?php echo base_url()?>public/images/star/icon-star-3.png',
        readOnly : true,
        half  : true,
        score : <?php echo $r;?>,
        space : true
     });  
</script>
```

### First page course image

[image]

In this course five stars are displaying and located in first page.

### Second page course image

[image]

In this course 10 stars are displaying and located in second page.

Is the above script is not binding in second page?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery `<script>` in the second page properly? Also, did you check that your code can't run twice (no loops or similar)

Comment: Try putting your script inside jQuery(document).ready(function{});.. Check your browser's console log for errors.

Comment: if your pagination is loading pages via `ajax` you need to call the script again after page load and wrap it inside `.read()` function

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes i am calling via ajax. How to call it again?

Comment: @chade_ second time also control come to the same page

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling the pagination via ajax, then you need to call your script after ajax response in the `success` function too. But the problem is that your score needs to be specific to every book/item, you need to change the

```
score : <?php echo $r;?>
```

and

```
$('.rating_<?php echo $row->courseId;?>')
```

and get the `score` via `javascript` rather than `php` and move the function into `ajax` success. Now to get the data from the `javascript` and removing `php` you need to use `data` attributes for this purpose add the rating like `data-rating=<?=r?>` whie populating the html via php and then use `.each` and iterate all elements and get the respective `data-rating` attribute in `javacript` via `$(element).data('rating')` and assign to the rate option. You can see the below example how to populate the rating based on the data attrbutes you just need to copy this javascript and update you html accordingly and you are done.

```js
$('.rating').each(function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  $(ele).raty({
    starOff: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.8.0/images/star-off.png',
    starOn: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.8.0/images/star-on.png',
    starHalf: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.8.0/images/star-half.png',
    readOnly: true,
    half: true,
    score: ele.data('rating'),
    space: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.8.0/jquery.raty.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.8.0/jquery.raty.js"></script>

<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="3"></div>
</div>

<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="4"></div>
</div>
<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="1"></div>
</div>
<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="5"></div>
</div>
<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="4"></div>
</div>
<div class="ft-item">
  <div class="rating" data-rating="4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to bind the above code when the second page loads. How to do that?